# Adding minutes to a given time

Tags: java, time, indexof

I need to create a program that adds minutes to a time given by the user.
So far i have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LaterTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a time in the format Hour:Minutes ");
        String Time = scan.next();
    }
}
```

I know I need to find the index of the ":" and my feeling is use modulo and addition to solve, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You could simple use the Date/Time APIs, parse the value, update the value and format it back again

Comment: I agree. Use the Data/Time APIs. They are well tested and useful (even if not really well designed JodaTime is much  better). See last part of answer from @Matoni from a good example. The comment below from the poster makes this sound like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split

```
String[] parts = time.split(":");
String hours = parts[0];
String minutes = parts[1];
```

Or you can use substring method

```
String minutes = time.substring(time.indexOf(':'), time.length());
```

Converting minutes from `String` to `int`

```
int m = Integer.parseInt(minutes);
```

Adding minutes to a time given by user:

```
int userHours = ...;
int userMinutes = ...;

int parsedMinutes = ...;

int extraHours = (userMinutes + parsedMinutes) / 60;
int remainingMinutes = (userMinutes + parsedMinutes) % 60; // modulo i.e. remainder after division 

int hours = (userHours + extraHours) % 24; 
int minutes = remainingMinutes;
```

You can use `TimeUnit` for conversions between time units:

```
int extraHours = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(userMinutes + parsedMinutes);
int remainingMinutes = (userMinutes + parsedMinutes) - extraHours * 60;
```

In case, you need to format number with leading zero (5 -> "05", 23 -> "23")

```
String formatted = String.format("%02d", number); // 2 decimal places
```

Result printing

```
System.out.println("resulting time in HH:mm format: " 
        + String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes));
```

Note, you can achieve the same result with the following code (all the math is done by `Calendar`):

```
Date now = new Date();

// set time given by user
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(now);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, userHours);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, userMinutes);
Date date = cal.getTime();

// add minutes 
cal.setTime(userDateTime);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, parsedMinutes);
Date updated = cal.getTime();

// date formats
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm);
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

System.out.println(dateTimeFormat.format(updated));
System.out.println(timeFormat.format(updated));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String time1 = sc.nextLine();
        String time2 = sc.nextLine();
        String[] time1parse = time1.split(":");
        String hour1 = time1parse[0];
        int hour1int = Integer.parseInt(hour1);
        String minutes1 = time1parse[1];
        int minutes1int = Integer.parseInt(minutes1)(
        String time2parse = time2.split(":");
        String hour2 = time2parse[0];
        int hour2int = Integer.parseInt(hour2);
        String minutes2 = time2parse[1];
        int minutes2int = Integer.parseInt(minutes2);



        //Math
        int minutes=minutes1int+minutes2int;
        int hours=hours1int+hours2int;
        hours+=minutes%60;
        minutes-=(minutes%60)*60;
        System.out.println(hours+":"+minutes);
    }
}
```

What I did with the code was accept 2 inputs, then I parsed them using the split method of the string class. I then converted the string arrays into different strings. After that, I made those strings into integers. Then finally I did the math and converted all the minutes and hours into actual units.

Comment: well i was given some guidelines...here are what they are
   
        Read the date.
        Make a copy of the date.
        Find the index of the ':'. 
        Copy the hour part out of the time to a new variable.
        Parse the hour string into a number.
        Next save the minutes into a different variable
        Parse the minutes
        Add the new minutes to the recently parsed minutes
        Adjust the number of minutes to only be 0-59 and add the number of hours, if needed to the hours. Also adjust the hours to be 0-23 if needed.
        Print the results!

Comment: @Grant Clark:  Your comment reads like you've (or someone else has) broken down the problem into steps you can code.  So, go and do, or tell us in another question which of these steps you're stuck on.